# For loops in Bash

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I'm running the bioinformatics tool hmmer and I would like to run it for over 7000 test sequence queries. After it runs each one, I would like it to save the output in a text file, which it does quite easily.

I am trying to create a for loop in bash that would run hmmer on each test sequence in the folder and writes the output to its own text file.

How does one write a statement inside the for loop so that it writes to a different text file each time the loop is performed?

Currently my code is as such

```
for i in First10/*; do

binaries/jackhmmer --tblout test[i].txt -E1 --noali $i largedatabase.fasta

done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in First10/*; do
     binaries/jackhmmer --tblout test$(basename $i).txt -E1 --noali $i largedatabase.fasta
done
```

I am not sure about the command you are running in the loop. But I think my answer can fulfill your requirement.

It will create new output file in every loop. 
**i.e: If you have two files called `database1.db` and `database2.db` in `First10` directory, in the first loop it will create output `testdatabase1.db.txt` and `testdatabase2.db.txt` in second loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd First10 
  for filename in *; do

        ../binaries/jackhmmer --tblout "${filename}.log" -E1 --noali "$filename" largedatabase.fasta 

  done
 cd $OLDPWD
```

So you will have the processed file name on the log file name dot log, changing its name for each iteration.